# How to configure Windows Performance DataCollectors to note DST properly?

Tags: windows, performancecounter

I'm trying to use Windows performance counters to monitor machine health as part of my application. I have some DataCollectors configured to write out data to either CSV or BLG format. However, I note that timestamps do not have TZ information per sample timestamp, just once per file. This means in a single file of data I will see things like:

```
"(PDH-CSV 4.0) (GMT Standard Time)(-60)","\\MACHINE-NAME\% C2 Time"
"10/29/2017 01:59:44.562","88.359340674585567"
"10/29/2017 01:59:59.562","93.754278507632279"
"10/29/2017 01:00:14.562","89.834673388599242"
"10/29/2017 01:00:29.563","94.014449309223536"
```

Similarly in the transition the other way you see a missing hour of data (which is harder to disambiguate vs a machine being offline for that hour).

I thought perhaps the binary data might store more information, so I created the same metrics in BLG format too, and used PowerShell to read the information back. However, in that case I still can't get timezone information per timestamp. E.g.,

```
# $counters = Import-Counter -Path mysamples.blg

# $counters[10].Timestamp
29 October 2017 01:59:59

# $counters[11].Timestamp
29 October 2017 01:00:14

# $counters[10].Timestamp.IsDaylightSavingTime()
False
# $counters[11].Timestamp.IsDaylightSavingTime()
False

# $counters[10].Timestamp.ToFileTimeUtc()
131537159995620000
# $counters[11].Timestamp.ToFileTimeUtc()
131537124145620000
```

Is there any way to get the correct TZ information associated with a timestamp in performance counter data, or is there a way to add a UTC time to the log rather than a TZ offset timestamp?

Comment: Ran into this same issue and stumbled on your post looking for a solution. Dangit.  I do know it's possible to do the UTC calculation as the data is recorded.  Also, the PerfCounter data tends to have a parallel WMI table Win32_PerfRawData table which displays the timestamps in UTC time, so someone somewhere knows how to do the conversion.

Comment: Hi @Michael ,i'm curious how you manage to get the full Timestamp in the output. I'm using the following command line to create a bin log file:
 `code Logman.exe create counter perf21 -f bin  -v mmddhhmm -si 00:01 -c "\Process(*)\" -o "C:\perf\2.blg" `

but all i get in the timestamp is the minutes and seconds for example 55.21